# Deploy Python Command-Line Application

Tags: python-3.x

So I wrote a little Command-Line App and want to provide an easy way to clone and use it. Problem: My app has some dependencies like Hashlib and Pyperclip.

Is there a best practice to get missing packages installed on a different machine?

- Can I do so without people needing to install global pip packages?

  - It is a good idea to ship it as a `venv`?
  - Can like `compile` them into a single python file (somewhat like a binary)?
- If I cannot do so, how to I get packages installed on a different machine?

Is there a nice routine to allow the user to completely remove my app once installed?

Comment: You want to use a `setup.py` and then upload it to pypi. Then people can just do `python -m pip install <yourlib>` and it will get all the dependencies

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [py2exe](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py2exe/0.9.2.0) module to make a standalone application for the Windows platform. You can use [py2app](https://pythonhosted.org/py2app/) to make standalone apps on the Mac platform. For Linux, you should prepare a package using the .deb format to target the Ubuntu/Debian environment (which is one of the most popular flavors of *nix). Each other *nix flavor has its own packaging system that you would have to follow to target it as a platform.